# Why special characters like üöä are not displayed in notifications in android when using FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to display a notification but when the message contains letters like ü, it's displayed a blank space. I read different topics on this subject and maybe is something regarding the encoding, but I'm not sure. My class extends FirebaseMessagingService. Maybe it's something regarding the encoding?

I sent the message "Test-üöä" and the result is displayed down bellow.

This is the result: [image]

This is my OnMessageReceivedMethod

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    data = remoteMessage.getData();

    String mandatorId = data.get(MANDATOR_ID);
    String message = data.get(MESSAGE);
    String serialNumber = data.get(PM_ID);

    if (message != null) {
        Log.i("OnMessageReceived: ", message);
        if (isForeground(this, PACKAGE_NAME)) {
            sendDialogNotification(mandatorId, message, serialNumber);
        } else {
            sendNotification(mandatorId, message, serialNumber);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("OnMessageReceived", "null error");
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions! Thanks

Comment: Is this related to firebase or the display? Print the message length, is it 5 or 8?

Comment: @AndyTurner the length it's 6..

Comment: Well... that's unexpected. What are those 6 characters?

Comment: @AndyTurner I set the message to "Test-ü" and the length is 5

Comment: But if I print the message in logs, it shows "Test-"